# How to authenticate glassfish docroot folder

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I would like to add authentication to glassfish v3.1.1 docroot folder.
I have my `javadoc` folder pasted to `domains\domainX\docroot` folder.  What I am trying to accomplish is when I open the URL `http:\\hostname:8080\javadoc` I need an authentication page to appear (file realm) before displaying `index.html` page.

I have read [Defining Security Constraints on Content under Glassfish Docroot](http://blogs.oracle.com/monzillo/entry/defining_secuirty_constraints_on_web) 
, but couldn't implement it on GF 3.1.1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What step of the process gave you trouble? Was there an explicit error message that you need help resolving?

Comment: @vkraemer In step 5, I don't see the pull-down list labeled with my web application context root.

Comment: The instructions that you are reading appear to be for older GF server implementations. Have you looked under Configurations->server-config->Virtual Servers->server for the combo-box labeled 'Default Web Module'?

Comment: @vkraemer Thanks, I was looking at my standalone instance config instead of server-config.  Now I have two issues; 1) I'm getting `Suspicious url pattern: "/\*" in context [/MyProject] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification ` in server logs 2) `http:\\hostname:8080` gives HTTP 500

Comment: There is additional info on alternate docroots available here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaft.html#geqpl.  have you tried 'property name="alternatedocroot_1" 
                 value="from=/* dir=docroot"' instead?

Comment: I am getting following error while adding MyProject as Default Web Module in Virtual Server `SEVERE: Update virtual server failed.  parent=http://localhost:4848/management/domain/servers/server/MyOtherInstance/application-ref/MyProject; attrsMap ={virtualServers=server}`